# Relieving is approved from HR side but he applied own terms and conditions for F&F due to COVID-19

Tags: professionalism, recruitment, human-resources, india, covid-19

I resigned from my current company (a German MNC) on 16 of March 20. 
Yesterday, 14 of April 20 was my last working day as per my job contract. My HR relieved me on 14 of April, but he applied some terms and conditions.

He mailed me: Your relieving is approved and last working date with XYZ is 14<sup>th</sup> Apr 20. But due to COVID-19 he mentioned in the mail that when the office is reopened I should come to the office and give handover and training to my old team, then they would clear my F&F.

I replied to the same mail that I can only expend one or two days for my handover process. I have one laptop, data card, punching card, and laptop bag which I will return on the same day and will complete other formalities also. But 16 of April is my joining date in my next employment.

Please guide me so they will relieve me via mail, so I can join my next employment.

Comment: Relieving letters don't exist in Germany, so this should not be a problem. Your last working day is still April 14, so on April 16 you're free to start working at your new job.

Comment: What does F&F mean? And please invest some minutes to fix the worst typing mistakes.

Comment: Have you contacted them yet about doing this via mail? Is there a reason they don't want you to just ship your things back or have you not had that discussion?

Comment: What is F&F? Native German and never heard the term. Generally in Germany there is not much they can do if you refuse!

Comment: F&F? is full and final, job location in India company origin Germany.

Comment: Ok, so Indian labor laws apply? That makes the answers pretty much invalid. You should change the country tag!

Comment: The nationality of the company doesnt matter, you are operating under Indian law so Indian law applies regardless.

Answer (score 2):

1. Your reliving is already approved and it is sufficient to join the new company. Everyone knows the situation that due to lockdown people cannot come to office and hence cannot return company property. Only your full and final is withheld, subject to you returning the assets and completing KT.
2. KT period : The best course is to negotiate this with your manager ( the one who manages the old team where you need to give handover) and understand what is needed. This should have been done by you in your notice period. If you have done the same, document that in an email and ask your manager to acknowledge that KT is complete.
3. If KT is not done, prepare a KT plan and find out its duration. Are there other people in the team with similar skill set? Do you possess any knowledge which is unique and is not known to other team members? Do you have documents to cover what needs to be done in your role ( e.g. how to do a certain task like build etc). If not, can you prepare some documents?

Due to COVID-19 situation, employees are locked in and cannot go to office to return the hardware. In such instances, F&F is withheld to ensure that the property is returned safely. Your company HR has gone one step ahead and included a KT disclaimer.

In most cases, handover has to be negotiated with the manager rather than HR. If you already have trained a back up, then there should be no concern as you don't need a KT period and manager can waive it off. If not, you can follow step 3, create documentation to help someone play your role. You can ask your manager for the new person to go through the documentation and redirect any questions to you, which you can address in person for one day when you come to office for your F&F.

It is best to negotiate something which suits both parties rather than get into a fight. If its 2-3 days, I would recommend you take a few days off from your new office and get it done. If you will explain it to HR/manager in your new company, they will understand as they would have a few similar cases and accommodate you. If the old company asks for something extensive, then a lot will depend on your relationship and negotiation skills.

You can put your foot down if they ask for an extended KT, however, the laws are pretty grey and wont help you. Worse case scenario would be to ask them to document the extended KT duration in writing and approach a lawyer. Most organizations will back off, unless someone wants to make an example out of you.